# Outgoing email marked as spam in outlook, despite getting all passes from isnotspam.com

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spamassassin

Here is the report from isnotspam.com (below)

> http://www.isnotspam.com/newlatestreport.php?email=ins-4wz6aize%40isnotspam.com

Despite passing all the checks we're still going into spam. Can someone please help me identify from the feedback in the link what we need to change?

I wanted to put the full report into this question but stack overflow formatting did not allow me.

here is email content:

> Hi, Jdhd Bdhdhd
> Thank you for signing up to luvdup.
> Before you can fully use the app, please verify your email
>   address by clicking the link below: 
>   http://controlpanel.luvdupapp.com/api/activation/03ab6e9c971b09de669fff16117c6785'>
>   Activation.
> Regards,
> luvdup Team

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Because the both are unrelated. (Unrelated means you cannot deduct anything from what is being reported by isnotspam (except maybe for what you can read there))

Furthermore, you dont know how someone else's spam detection is setup. E.g. we block/mark everything from the amazon abuse cloud.

Comment: I don't agree at all. You can absolutely change the things about your outgoing emails that isnotspam is reporting on. Indeed, that's the entire point of it.

And when you have a high spam score, you often end up in spam. Once again, that's the whole point of it.